# How can I do UpdateSelectInput work correctly?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm trying to update a selectInput in shinyapp but it doesn't work correctly. When I change the input of `datalab_data`, the choices in the selectinput `datalab_columns` don't change and it keep the column names of Events. I hope someone can help me with this part of code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)

header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = "dashboard_shiny", titleWidth = 250
)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  width = 250,
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Data Lab", tabName = "datalab", icon = icon("flask"))
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem("datalab",
            fluidRow(
              column(6, wellPanel(radioButtons("datalab_data", "Select data source:", choices = c("Events", "Worknotes", "Occupations")))),
              column(6, wellPanel(selectInput("datalab_columns", "Select data columns:", choices = "All Columns", multiple = T)))
            )
           )
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

observeEvent(input$datalab_data != "", {
    
    if(input$datalab_data == "Events"){
      columns <- events() %>% colnames()
    }
    
    if(input$datalab_data == "Worknotes"){
      columns <- worknotes() %>% colnames()
    }
    
    if(input$datalab_data == "Occupations"){
      columns <- occupations() %>% colnames()
    }
    
    updateSelectInput(session = session, inputId = "datalab_columns", choices = c("All Columns", columns), selected = "All Columns")
    
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: events(), worknotes() and occupations() are not given in your example code. Howver, using mtcars and iris your code works fine and the slelectInput is updated. Therefore I could only guess that the issue is related to the missing parts. Maybe you could include the missing parts in your example code.

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine.
I imported only shiny and shinydashboard.
And i also change the pipeing for the columenames to a normal call colnames(xxx) on my sample objects